# Do you update your Unit Tests after updating your original source code?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I am so sorry for a noob sounding question.
So, I understand unit testing. Of late, I have come across a situation where there is additional methods needed for a class used in a project and redesigning of some methods as well. Do I have to update the unit tests as well?

Philosophically, after you update the code base, are you supposed to keep the same unit test suite or update the unit test suite as well?

Comment: Nope. I update them BEFORE updating the original source code.

Comment: Are you talking about TDD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I have to update the unit tests as well?

Adding new methods should not require *functional* changes in existing methods/test.

> Philosophically, after you update the code base, are you supposed to keep the same unit test suite or update the unit test suite as well?

It all narrows down to whether *class contract* changes. Contract changes include:

- you add/remove dependencies
- you change dependencies contract
- you make functional change to code (method works differently than previously)

Any of the above will require change in tests. On the other hand, tests should remain intact when:

- you refactor your code
- you *extend* your class (like adding new methods)

Comment: Appreciate it! Thanks for your thoughts.